Quarkus qute 3.16 broken
we used Quarkus Qute 3.15.2 and all worked fine. Since 3.16.1 we have an issue with calling a Java method. The parameter in the Java method is always the same value where in the HTML file the field has the correct value within a loop.
Html fragments:
{#for project in schedules.projects}
  {#for name in schedules.names}
    <script>console.log("Name: Project.name = [{project.name}]");</script>
    {#let schedule = schedules.forProjectAndName(project, name, project_index)}
    ........
  {/for}
{/for}

In the browser console logging, the value for project.name is correct for each project in 'schedules.projects'
Java Code:
public PipelineSchedule forProjectAndName(final Project project, final String scheduleName, final int indexCount) {
log.info("Name: Project.Name = [{}], ScheduleName = [{}], indexCount = [{}]", project.name(), scheduleName, indexCount);

The java logging shows always the first project name from the loop in the html code.
Anyone an idea what is going on? And how to solve this?
Thanks.

You are still in the first loop, and as such it is always the first (PROJECT) that then you have an inner shedule loop running for the first project, until that project is done

are you also closing the for loop?

If you mean the '{/for}': yes it is there for each loop. These loops worked fine in 3.15.2.

Solved by adding @TemplateData to the main PoJo.
See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/44797

I faced a similar problem in my project. Adding @TemplateData annotation on model class works as an workaround. The fix will probably be available in 3.17.3 Quarkus version.
